# Nasdaq API Usage

Tags: software, data-ownership, securities, data

I, [and others](https://towardsdev.com/web-scraping-accessing-nasdaq-api-4fd83c8172ff), have discovered that [Nasdaq's website](https://www.nasdaq.com/) is powered by an API which has the endpoint `api.nasdaq.com`. As far as I can tell, it is fully legal to scrape Nasdaq's website (correct me if I'm wrong; I can't find anything in their terms of use prohibiting it). Is it legal for me to use the `api.nasdaq.com` API for a commercial product or for personal use?

I am not referencing any of the consumer facing APIs that Nasdaq has available. These API have the endpoint `data.nasdaq.com` and are well documented.